# Android Studio broke my App

Tags: android, backend

Not so familiar with Android studio as I keep running into problems.  My app was running fine until something broke in relation to the cloud backend, which I never touched and this error keeps me from continuing:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
C:\Users\JC\Projects\ca.usimage.resto.RestonetActivity\backend\build\generated-source\endpoints\java\com\example\jean\myapplication\backend\myApi\MyApi.java:279: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
C:\Users\JC\Projects\ca.usimage.resto.RestonetActivity\backend\build\generated-source\endpoints\java\com\example\jean\myapplication\backend\myApi\MyApi.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
      return (Builder) super.setBatchPath(batchPath);
                            ^
  symbol: method setBatchPath(String)
2 errors
1 warning
```

I upgraded to Android Studio 3, updated everything I could, even backtracked to a new project from a year old github backup  and I still get the error.

What went wrong?

About to reinstall Android Studio, or switch back to Eclipse (yuck)

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */
/*
 * This code was generated by https://github.com/google/apis-client-generator/
 * (build: 2017-11-07 19:12:12 UTC)
 * on 2017-11-21 at 02:13:58 UTC 
 * Modify at your own risk.
 */

package com.example.jean.myapplication.backend.myApi;

/**
 * Service definition for MyApi (v1).
 *
 * <p>
 * This is an API
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * For more information about this service, see the
 * <a href="" target="_blank">API Documentation</a>
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * This service uses {@link MyApiRequestInitializer} to initialize global parameters via its
 * {@link Builder}.
 * </p>
 *
 * @since 1.3
 * @author Google, Inc.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class MyApi extends com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient {

  // Note: Leave this static initializer at the top of the file.
  static {
    com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkState(
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.MAJOR_VERSION == 1 &&
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.MINOR_VERSION >= 15,
        "You are currently running with version %s of google-api-client. " +
        "You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version " +
        "1.23.0 of the myApi library.", com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.VERSION);
  }

  /**
   * The default encoded root URL of the service. This is determined when the library is generated
   * and normally should not be changed.
   *
   * @since 1.7
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "https://myApplicationId.appspot.com/_ah/api/";

  /**
   * The default encoded service path of the service. This is determined when the library is
   * generated and normally should not be changed.
   *
   * @since 1.7
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "myApi/v1/sayHi/";

  /**
   * The default encoded batch path of the service. This is determined when the library is
   * generated and normally should not be changed.
   *
   * @since 1.23
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_BATCH_PATH = "batch";

  /**
   * The default encoded base URL of the service. This is determined when the library is generated
   * and normally should not be changed.
   */
  public static final String DEFAULT_BASE_URL = DEFAULT_ROOT_URL + DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   *
   * <p>
   * Use {@link Builder} if you need to specify any of the optional parameters.
   * </p>
   *
   * @param transport HTTP transport, which should normally be:
   *        <ul>
   *        <li>Google App Engine:
   *        {@code com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport}</li>
   *        <li>Android: {@code newCompatibleTransport} from
   *        {@code com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp}</li>
   *        <li>Java: {@link com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport#newTrustedTransport()}
   *        </li>
   *        </ul>
   * @param jsonFactory JSON factory, which may be:
   *        <ul>
   *        <li>Jackson: {@code com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory}</li>
   *        <li>Google GSON: {@code com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory}</li>
   *        <li>Android Honeycomb or higher:
   *        {@code com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory}</li>
   *        </ul>
   * @param httpRequestInitializer HTTP request initializer or {@code null} for none
   * @since 1.7
   */
  public MyApi(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport, com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory,
      com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
    this(new Builder(transport, jsonFactory, httpRequestInitializer));
  }

  /**
   * @param builder builder
   */
  MyApi(Builder builder) {
    super(builder);
  }

  @Override
  protected void initialize(com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> httpClientRequest) throws java.io.IOException {
    super.initialize(httpClientRequest);
  }

  /**
   * Create a request for the method "sayHi".
   *
   * This request holds the parameters needed by the myApi server.  After setting any optional
   * parameters, call the {@link SayHi#execute()} method to invoke the remote operation.
   *
   * @param name
   * @return the request
   */
  public SayHi sayHi(java.lang.String name) throws java.io.IOException {
    SayHi result = new SayHi(name);
    initialize(result);
    return result;
  }

  public class SayHi extends MyApiRequest<com.example.jean.myapplication.backend.myApi.model.MyBean> {

    private static final String REST_PATH = "{name}";

    /**
     * Create a request for the method "sayHi".
     *
     * This request holds the parameters needed by the the myApi server.  After setting any optional
     * parameters, call the {@link SayHi#execute()} method to invoke the remote operation. <p> {@link
     * SayHi#initialize(com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest)} must
     * be called to initialize this instance immediately after invoking the constructor. </p>
     *
     * @param name
     * @since 1.13
     */
    protected SayHi(java.lang.String name) {
      super(MyApi.this, "POST", REST_PATH, null, com.example.jean.myapplication.backend.myApi.model.MyBean.class);
      this.name = com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(name, "Required parameter name must be specified.");
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setAlt(java.lang.String alt) {
      return (SayHi) super.setAlt(alt);
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setFields(java.lang.String fields) {
      return (SayHi) super.setFields(fields);
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setKey(java.lang.String key) {
      return (SayHi) super.setKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setOauthToken(java.lang.String oauthToken) {
      return (SayHi) super.setOauthToken(oauthToken);
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setPrettyPrint(java.lang.Boolean prettyPrint) {
      return (SayHi) super.setPrettyPrint(prettyPrint);
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setQuotaUser(java.lang.String quotaUser) {
      return (SayHi) super.setQuotaUser(quotaUser);
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi setUserIp(java.lang.String userIp) {
      return (SayHi) super.setUserIp(userIp);
    }

    @com.google.api.client.util.Key
    private java.lang.String name;

    /**

     */
    public java.lang.String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public SayHi setName(java.lang.String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public SayHi set(String parameterName, Object value) {
      return (SayHi) super.set(parameterName, value);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Builder for {@link MyApi}.
   *
   * <p>
   * Implementation is not thread-safe.
   * </p>
   *
   * @since 1.3.0
   */
  public static final class Builder extends com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder {

    /**
     * Returns an instance of a new builder.
     *
     * @param transport HTTP transport, which should normally be:
     *        <ul>
     *        <li>Google App Engine:
     *        {@code com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport}</li>
     *        <li>Android: {@code newCompatibleTransport} from
     *        {@code com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp}</li>
     *        <li>Java: {@link com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport#newTrustedTransport()}
     *        </li>
     *        </ul>
     * @param jsonFactory JSON factory, which may be:
     *        <ul>
     *        <li>Jackson: {@code com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory}</li>
     *        <li>Google GSON: {@code com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory}</li>
     *        <li>Android Honeycomb or higher:
     *        {@code com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory}</li>
     *        </ul>
     * @param httpRequestInitializer HTTP request initializer or {@code null} for none
     * @since 1.7
     */
    public Builder(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport, com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory,
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
      super(
          transport,
          jsonFactory,
          DEFAULT_ROOT_URL,
          DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH,
          httpRequestInitializer,
          false);
      setBatchPath(DEFAULT_BATCH_PATH);
    }

    /** Builds a new instance of {@link MyApi}. */
    @Override
    public MyApi build() {
      return new MyApi(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setRootUrl(String rootUrl) {
      return (Builder) super.setRootUrl(rootUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setServicePath(String servicePath) {
      return (Builder) super.setServicePath(servicePath);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) {
      return (Builder) super.setBatchPath(batchPath);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setHttpRequestInitializer(com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
      return (Builder) super.setHttpRequestInitializer(httpRequestInitializer);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
      return (Builder) super.setApplicationName(applicationName);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setSuppressPatternChecks(boolean suppressPatternChecks) {
      return (Builder) super.setSuppressPatternChecks(suppressPatternChecks);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setSuppressRequiredParameterChecks(boolean suppressRequiredParameterChecks) {
      return (Builder) super.setSuppressRequiredParameterChecks(suppressRequiredParameterChecks);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setSuppressAllChecks(boolean suppressAllChecks) {
      return (Builder) super.setSuppressAllChecks(suppressAllChecks);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link MyApiRequestInitializer}.
     *
     * @since 1.12
     */
    public Builder setMyApiRequestInitializer(
        MyApiRequestInitializer myapiRequestInitializer) {
      return (Builder) super.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(myapiRequestInitializer);
    }

    @Override
    public Builder setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer googleClientRequestInitializer) {
      return (Builder) super.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(googleClientRequestInitializer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The message points out that no super class has been found for you to Override a method. It would be better if you showed up the code, and the class definition.

Comment: Here's the code which the error points to  MyApi.java.   I did not create this and never edited this file.  Frankly I have no clue what it's for:

Comment: Post it as an edit on the question, please

Comment: Please excuse my awkward question format... I rarely post questions... I do so when I get desparate

Comment: This is odd... I really can't figure this out.  I reinstalled Android Studio 2.2 and I still get this error.  I checked the VCS history and I never modified this MyApi.java file.  What is it used for?

Comment: Are you sure that `AbstractGoogleJsonClient` is the right class you want to extend? Take a look at the dependencies, did you change any? Updated, downgraded it? Were you using deprecated methods that might've been removed? There are lots of things that could've happened.